# Android_Studio Error

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User_Name.gradle\caches\2.14.1\classAnalysis\cache.properties (System cannot find the file)

Android-Studio show this error message and I don't know what it is or what should I do.

It show this when I try to run an app and I answer "Proceed without Instant Run" to this question:
"Instant Run requires that the platform corresponding to your target device (Android 1.0) is installed."

Answer (score 1):

At first **Upgrade SDK Manager .**

This exception is thrown during a failed attempt to open the file denoted by a specified pathname.

You can use

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:current_version'`
 & Use this

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:current_version'`

**Then Clean-Rebuild Your Project .**

Answer (score 0):

As my opinion , this type of error found When your app run in Instant Run feature of Android Studio. so, new build not generated every time and app content not found in your android device.
Click here to get solution

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run

Comment: you should add important part from the link in your answer and add link for further references.

Answer (score 0):

Delete folder config in C:/user/user/.android